# How to hide Template Field Edit column in Gridview based on Gridview Row Count

Tags: asp.net, gridview

I have a gridview, where i can add/delete rows. I dont want to give the delete option on the first row, that is I can delete any row but not the first one. How can i disable edit option for the first row ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can disable that cell from [GridView.RowDataBound](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.rowdatabound.aspx) as you have used Template field, you can use `FindControl` method and then disable that cell..

```
protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
    if (e.Row.RowIndex == 0)
    { 
        //Disable that cell here..
    }
}
```

Comment: Exactly what I was looking for !! Thnx.